# JS - Force input number leading zeros

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, input, numbers

I'm trying to force my input[type="number"] elements to add a leading zero whenever the value is smaller than 10. This is a very easy script

```
jQuery('input[type="number"]').on('change', function() {
    if(jQuery(this).val() < 10) {
        jQuery(this).val('0'+jQuery(this).val());
    }
});
```

This works fine on chrome but firefox removes every leading zero from number inputs. I know I can use a text or tel type input with a pattern, but it's important for my app that it has the little "+" and "-" arrows to add and decrease 1 respectively.

Is there any way to force firefox to add the leading zeros?

**EDIT:**

Appaerently you can't change firefox's behaviour towards this type of input... so I changed the ones in my page to `<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" max="59" name="minutes">`

And added this bit of JS

```
function add_leading_zero(element) {
    if(jQuery(element).val() < 10)
        jQuery(element).val('0'+jQuery(element).val());
}

jQuery('input[type="tel"]').keydown(function(e) {
    var max = jQuery(this).attr('max');
    var val = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 38: // arrow up
            if(val < max) {
                jQuery(this).val(val+1);
                add_leading_zero(this);
            }
        break;
        case 40: // arrow down
            if(val > 0) {
                jQuery(this).val(val-1);
                add_leading_zero(this);
            }
        break
        default:
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not think 01 or 02 is a valid number and it may be the default behaviour of other browsers treat it as a string, not a valid Number.

Comment: I guess FF assumes that since the field is a number, leading zeroes are insignificant and removes them automatically.

Comment: You could implement the `+/-` control with your own JS, instead of depending on the browser's built-in control.

Comment: You can use type=text and class number..after you manage onkeydown event for accept only number..

Comment: Yeap, I did a bit more research and appaerently it's a lot better to use another input type and just add the +/- functionality myself. I'll post it after in case someone else needs it in the future.